# Python соединить элементы в кортежах, которые находятся внутри списка

Tags: python, списки

Прошу подсказать как можно соединить элементы в кортежах, которые находятся внутри списка, ибо в интернете нашел только примеры с обычными списками.

Нужно сделать из этого:

```
[('Товар1', 155, '$',), ('Товар2', 155, '$',) ...]
```

Это:

```
[('Товар1 155$',), ('Товар2 155$',) ...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если совсем просто и без украшательств, то так:

```
lst = [('Товар1', 155, '$',), ('Товар2', 155, '$',)]
print([(' '.join(list(map(str,x))),) for x in lst])
```

На выходе:

```
[('Товар1 155 $',), ('Товар2 155 $',)]
```

Comment: А можете ещё подсказать как на выходе получить просто Товар1 155 $, Товар2 155 $ (без списка кортежей, просто строку)

Comment: @CoffeeinTime - поскольку у нас list comprehension, то на выходе все равно будет iterable - можно сделать просто: `print([' '.join(list(map(str,x))) for x in lst])` - получите список со строками вида `['Товар1 155 $', 'Товар2 155 $']`

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [('Товар1', 155, '$',), ('Товар2', 155, '$',)]
```

Если нужно просто вывести через `print`:

```
print(*[' '.join(map(str, k)) for k in lst], sep=', ')
# Товар1 155 $, Товар2 155 $
```

Если нужно получить строковую переменную то:

```
lp = ', '.join(' '.join(map(str, k)) for k in lst)
print(lp)  # Товар1 155 $, Товар2 155 $
```

Если нужно `$` написать слитно с цифрой то:

```
lp = ', '.join(' '.join(map(str, k)).replace(' $', '$') for k in lst)
print(lp) # Товар1 155$, Товар2 155$
```